# Is it possible to find if a combination of an array the size of 5 can make exactly 15?

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I'm kind of new to programming, I have gotten values from an array the size of 5.
From this array, I need to see if any combination of 3 of those 5 numbers can make 15, is there any way this is possible?

Ex. Array[2] + Array[4] + Array[1] = 15 even though there are 5 numbers within the array

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How would you try it by hand?

Comment: Also, read up on how to generate a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). In your case, since your array has 5 elements, you'll be making 32 trials (2**5) to decide whether the sum is 15. (Oh wait, I didn't see the part about selecting exactly 3 of the 5 elements. Oh well, you'll just have to filter down the results some.)

Comment: Are duplicates allowed? Eg. Array[1]+Array[1]+Array[2] = 15

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would go about it:

```
boolean sum15( int Array[5] ) {
    bool isUsed[5] = {0}; // Prevents duplicates

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) // Nested for loops iterate through every combo
    {
        isUsed[i] = true; // This makes it so the next loop doesn't use Array[i]
        for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        {
            if( isUsed[j] ) // Check if Array[i] was already used
                continue; // "Continue" restarts the loop, then increments 'j'
            isUsed[j] = true;
            for( int k = 0; k < 5; k++ )
            {
                if( isUsed[k] )
                    continue;
                if( Array[i] + Array[j] + Array[k] == 15 ) // Check if valid combo
                    return true;
            }
            isUsed[j] = false;
        }
        isUsed[i] = false;
    }
    return false; // No match was found
}
```

"is there any way this is possible?"
Where there is a will there is a way. For all problems, there is code that can solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This was along the lines of what I was thinking  - 3 loops within, but how to check if the number was already used was beyond me. Reading the code you printed, I'm still a little bit lost on how you checked if the array number was already used, could you please clarify that?

Comment: @user3610386 Hah, I didn't catch this comment, bit late of a response. When I'm about to use a given index `i`, I set `isUsed[i]` to `true`. In the inner loop iterating over `j`, I avoid any index where `isUsed[j]` is `true`. When I'm done with the inner loop, I set `isUsed[i]` back to `false`, so that future inner loops can use it again. If this is a correct answer, pls accept it :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
var source = new [] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

var query =
    from values in source.Selection(3)
    where values.Sum() == 15
    select values.ToArray();
```

I get this result:

[image]

Now, of course, you do need to define the `Selection` extension method. Its job is to select a list of all of the possible ways to select `count` number of elements from the source enumerable.

I defined it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Selection<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    return
        source
            .SelectMany((t, n) =>
                count == 1
                ? new [] { new [] { t }.AsEnumerable() }.AsEnumerable()
                : source
                    .Skip(n + 1)
                    .Selection(count - 1)
                    .Select(tt => new [] { t }.Concat(tt)));
}
```